# tcl expect creating starpack

Tags: tcl, expect, starkit

I'm using starkit/starpack with tcl8.5 and expect 5.44.1.15 under linux, after creating the starkit and putting the directory for expect under lib directory of the created vfs directory and wrap it back to starkit file, I could create the starpack file, after checking that everything's working fine on my linux system, I use this standalone file on another linux system but there, it doesn't work and I have this error :

```
couldn't load file "/tmp/tclJ4M144": /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /tmp/tclJ4M144)
```

so trying to solve this, I've removed expect 5.44.1.15 directory from vfs directory and replaced it with expect 5.43 taken from the target linux system (where my standalone starpack file didn't work), I've also adapted its pkgIndex file before recreating the starkit and then the starpack, but this time I have this error :

```
segmentation fault
```

Anyone can help me on this ? What do I need to do to make it work on the target linux system ?

Thank you.

Comment: The issue looks like a problem with different versions of glibc on the machine where the Tclkit binary was built and the Expect package was built. Damn Linux and its non-stable system library ABIs!

Comment: while Tcl's ABI is very stable.